# How can I execute a command when I first login to my unix server?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I want to execute "source mysite/bin/activate"

Whever I ssh into that server (and login)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write what ever command you want to run at the time of login in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file in the user's root directory ( `/home/myusername/.bashrc` ).

As pointed out by Alex Reece, alternatively, you can also look for `.login` [file](http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/dotlogin.html) and add the command there.

Comment: Actually, TIMEX probably wants `.login`

Comment: in rhel .bash_profile works not the .bashrc while login for the first time