# Run a Command When Terminal Opens (Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora

This feels like a stupid question, but I can't find an answer (that works) anywhere. So, I thought I'd ask it here.

Basically, I would like a command to run every time I open a Terminal window, and then show the output in the Terminal (I have Fedora). Is this possible with the MOTD, or is that text-only?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I execute a command when I first login to my unix server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128817/how-can-i-execute-a-command-when-i-first-login-to-my-unix-server)

Comment: Perhaps, but when I was trying to research this topic I saw that there may be different ways of doing this for SSH vs. Terminal in GUI. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in ~/.bashrc or equivalent.